# Apollo Client Cache Private Information

Tags: graphql, apollo-client

I am considering using Apollo client on an application that displays some private information about users. Is the way Apollo caches bad for this use case? Is there a way to selectively white list what you would like cached? Or is this not a problem at all because of the way Apollo caches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify if you want keep the result in your cache:

fetchPolicy "cache-first" | "cache-and-network" | "network-only" | "cache-only" | "no-cache" | "standby"
Specifies the FetchPolicy to be used for this query

More details here: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-apollo.html#graphql-config-options-fetchPolicy